# Can I pass a scope variable from AngularJS into LESS

Tags: css, angularjs, less

I have a variable defined in my AngularJS that counts the length of my array e.g. "array.length". I want to pass this into my LESS file as a variable e.g. @length = "array.length" so that I can use it change another class or variable...

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: what do you want to do in your css with the array.length variable?

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS executes within the browser.  LESS is processed on the server, before it is sent to the browser.  So, there is no direct way of accessing an AngularJS variable from LESS.

The best way forward, most likely, would be to set some CSS properties directly within the javascript code based on `array.length`.

Comment: You can also use [LESS on the client side](https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki/Client-side-usage) but I wouldn't recommend it for production.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing, as explained by [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19802366/5114164).
You could always use [`ng-class`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), however. It is a directive you can use for setting a CSS class through AngularJS; in this way you can choose which class you want to use for your element, and update it via AngularJS listeners.